# Add a list of lists to a list of lists with a list comprehension

Tags: python

I've got list of lists, (specifically the results of a results of a SQL query) that I want to add to the end of another list of lists (the results from a previous query/queries). The list comprehension that I think should do this

```
[results.append(result) for result in currentResults]
```

doesn't append the rows, but instead adds None where each row should be. However, if I do this with an if statement

```
for result in currentResults:
     results.append(result)
```

it works perfectly.

Why do these two statements not do the same thing, and is there a way to do this with a list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `.append()` is `None`.  That return value is what is going into your comprehension.

If the for loop works perfectly, then you should be able to just replace it with

```
results += list(currentResults)
```

Or, perhaps you might prefer:

```
results.extend(currentResults)
```

Comment: Thank you. Does exactly what I want.

Comment: No problem.  It was my honour to assist Bruce Way.. errr... I mean the Batman.  Damn, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension would work like:

```
results += [r for r in currentResults]
```